# What is the minimum gap needed for a windscreen on a cat can stove?

Tags: gear, diy

I've constructed a cat can jet stove as described [here](http://jwbasecamp.com/Articles/SuperCat/index.html).  He has a windscreen design, but it seems to be overkill (and doesn't work for my pot).  I've tried a couple of my own now, but they are all failing due to what appears to be not enough space between the wind shield and the pot.

What is the minimum gap needed between pot and windscreen to allow for a steady flame on alcohol jet such as the example given?

Comment: does your windscreen have holes around the bottom edge?

Comment: Yep, I put some for airflow

Answer (score 4):

I was hoping someone else would offer a more scientific answer, but here's my take on it.  You shouldn't need almost any ventilation around the top edge of your wind screen... A few small gaps, or even just a handful of punched holes above the level of your stove should be enough.  At the base of your windscreen though, you need a lot of holes to draw air in with.

I'm sorry I can't provide specifics, but if you have a windscreen that is failing now, start by adding a few holes at the bottom and retest.  Then add a few around the middle/top (~1" above the bottom edge of your pot).  Retest until satisfied :)